# Access UIView inside UIScrollView correctly

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I've this code:

```
int i=0;
for (UIView *view in [self subviews]) {
   //NSLog(@"index %d - i %d",index,i);
   if (i==index) {
      NSLog(@"index %d - i %d",index,i);
      [view setAlpha:0.3];
      [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
   }
   i++;
}
```

"index" is a variable used to select the view to modify.

The problem is that nothing happen, instead if I run this code:

```
for (UIView *view in [self subviews]) {
    [view setAlpha:0.3];
    [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

every view will be modify obviously, but i need the first code :)

ideas?

Comment: try setting tag to the view and check that with INDEX like 
if (view.tag==index) {
      [view setAlpha:0.3];
      [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
   }

even thought this is not a good way to do it..

Comment: I suggest you to use tags which uniquely identifies each view in scrolview instead indexes so that you can find your view in one-row code `[scrolview viewWithTag:tag]` and then perform any actions on it. The tag value can actually be the same value as index.

Comment: I haven't set any tag, indeed setting tag and using it to check, works very well, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **tag** of all the subviews inside your scroll view and then pass the tag of selected view to the index variable hope it is an integer.

```
 for(int i = 1; i <=4; i++){

  UIView *myView =  [UIView......]; // set your view
  myView.tag  = i;
  [your_scrollView addSubview:myView];
}
```

then you can do like following.

```
for (UIView *view in [your_scrollView subviews])
{
  if (view.tag == index) 
  {
  [view setAlpha:0.3];
  [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
  }
}
```

or there is an easy way to get the view  **[your_scrollView viewWithTag:index]**

Comment: Great it works! Thanks! answer checked! But I don't understand why, in my first code the NSLog write the right couple of value but the view remain the same...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
for (UIView *view in [scrollView subviews]) {
        [view setAlpha:0.3];
        [view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
```

Hope it works